# SQL Query to find unique values across multiple groups

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have a table in the format of:

> Name, url, xpath, value

The problem is Name A, B, and F have a url U1 and xpath X1 that are the same (don't care about value).

> Name C, D, E do not have that url U1 or did not have xpath X1.
>
> Name B, C, D, E may share U2 and X2

I am trying to find the best way to find where the URL and xpath exist in all Names (A-F).

I didn't know if i should create a temp table with all the unique values where URL and xpaths match. then use that temp table to go through all the names and if all the names have that URL and Xpath then add it to a second temp table, then i would just return all the results from the final temp table.

Thanks!

Here is some example data:

> Name, URL, Xpath, value
>
> John, /MyAttributes.xml, /attribute/arms, 2
>
> John, /MyAttributes.xml, /attributes/legs, 2
>
> John, /MyQualities.xml, /qualities/race, human
>
> Derek, /MyAttributes.xml, /attribute/legs, 2
> Derek, /MyQualities.xml, /qualities/race, non-human

So the names could grow to have hundreds of names, and the information i am trying to gather would be that "/MyAttributes.xml, /attributes/legs" exists in both John & Derek, and as the db grows i still need to be able to see which url with xpath exists across all names.

Hopefully that helps providing more data.

Comment: Some example data would clarify the question (i.e. not "do not have that URL", but actual column values)

Comment: @Andomar I have posted some additional data for reference. Sorry about not adding that with original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what i ended up doing. Thanks to everyone who helped. If you know a good way to optimize this that would be AWESOME.

To summarize i did end up creating a temp table. i then go through all the unique results. and see if that url + xpath exists on all the unique names. then if it does i insert it into  my temp table, where i just dump that out at the end.

```
    BEGIN
    DECLARE bDone INT;

      DECLARE var1 VARCHAR(845);
      DECLARE var2 VARCHAR(45);
      DECLARE var3 VARCHAR(800);

      DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(url, xpath), url, xpath FROM myTable;
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;


      DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tblResults;
      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblResults  (
        url VARCHAR(45),
        xpath VARCHAR(800)
      );
      OPEN curs;
      SET bDone = 0;
      REPEAT
        FETCH curs INTO var1, var2, var3;
        IF 
            (

            SELECT 
                COUNT(DISTINCT name) 
             FROM myTable as l 
             WHERE 
                l.url = var2 AND 
                l.xpath = var3
            ) = (

            SELECT 
                COUNT(DISTINCT name) 
                FROM myTable
            ) THEN

           INSERT INTO tblResults VALUES (var2, var3);
        END IF;
      UNTIL bDone END REPEAT;

      CLOSE curs;
      SELECT * FROM tblResults;
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select 
   url,
   xpath
from table
group by
   url,
   xpath
having
   max(case when name='A' then
         1
       else
         0
       end) +
   max(case when name='B' then
         2
       else
         0
       end) +
   max(case when name='C' then
         4
       else
         0
       end) +
   max(case when name='D' then
         8
       else
         0
       end) +
   max(case when name='E' then
         16
       else
         0
       end) +
   max(case when name='F' then
         32
       else
         0
       end) = 63;
```

Comment: Sorry in advance if this is not mysql format, I write SQL-92 in Oracle most of the time, though I think mysql is SQL-92 compliant.

Comment: Almost exactly where I was going, but you left off name ="F" to your binary addition simulation.

Comment: The problem with this is that the names will continue to grow and to maintain that list and continue to add them to this would be too much. If i had to i guess i could.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation on the answer submitted by Mark Bannister:

```
SELECT t.url
FROM
   myTable t
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS cnt FROM myTable) x
GROUP BY t.url
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.name) = MAX(x.cnt);
```

Comment: would it be better to have this as my base: `code` SELECT DISTINCT( CONCAT(url, xpath)) FROM myTable `code` then i could do a loop across all the names and if that url+path is in all of the names i could add that to my return list?

Comment: @Jtello A loop across all return values of a query with only matching values returned resolves to an inner join in SQL. However, as with any computer program, measurement (time, CPU, memory, disk usage) is essential. If you run a timed test of the pure SQL solution (optimized with indexes and SQL optimizer hints) and another timed test with the loop+match in code solution, most of the time the SQL solution wins. Also, you avoid lots of row-fetch operations across the network. Each way has pros and cons. That's why my advice would be to measure each way in your setup and decide based on that.

Comment: Yes I completely agree, seems though that there is a pure SQL way that will always be faster than a mix of SQL and PHP for my problem though. I know there are creative ways to do certain things like avoid the temp table or for loop i created. I posted the pure SQL solution that seems to be working for me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

To find all urls that exist for all names, try:

```
select url
from myTable
group by url
having count(distinct name) = (select count(distinct name) from myTable)
```

To find xpaths that exist for all names, swap xpath and url in the above query.

Comment: That's really great! Had not thought of this solution. It's more dynamic that mine since it does not depend on hard-coded name values.

Comment: The OP asked for xpath as well as url.  You'll probably want to correct this to include both in your select/group by.

Comment: Try reading the last sentence in the answer. (Including both in one query would give counts per *combination* of url *and* xpath.)

Comment: Would it be a good idea to move the 2nd SELECT as a cross join into the FROM so it does not get executed on every iteration? (assuming the SQL optimizer does not do this) Added another answer based on this twist below.